# Is bitcoin worth it?

Tags: mining-hardware

I have a couple of questions.  Is bitcoin the most profitable crypto currency right now how about in a year.  Is the Bitmain Antminer S1 Dual Blade 180 Gh/s Bitcoin Miner
A good miner?  Any suggestions good hashrate under 500 dollars?   Should I even start mining now or have I missed the train? Please answer as many of the questions you can.

Comment: Questions that ask for product recommendations or predictions of future economic conditions can't be answered definitively and are off topic here. Also, in general, please ask one question per post.

Comment: Bitcoin != Bitcoin mining.

Answer (score 1):

To get profitable mining in average you should have Miners with speed in Ths than Gh/s. Try checking the Bitcoin Mining Calculator to check how much profit you can make with the mining power you have.